# Windows 7 display is blurry/distorted after each reboot until the resolution is toggled

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, graphics-card, resolution

**Dell Optiplex 3020 / Windows 7 64-bit / Intel HD 4400 Graphics / Dell 2405FPW Monitor**

**Running at native 1920x1200 60Hz resolution using a VGA cable**

After starting up the display is blurry and the first inch of the left side of the desktop is cutoff. Changing the refresh rate from 60Hz to 59Hz and back fixes the problem as does toggling the resolution. **The problem is that this must be done after every reboot.**

It appears that there aren't any Windows 7 drivers for the 2405FPW monitor so Windows is using the Generic PnP Monitor drivers. I tried changing the driver to the generic Digital Flat Panel 1920x1200 driver but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using the www.intel.com drivers for HD4400?  Its a shame you can't use DP or DVI since both the onboard video and LCD don't share an interface beyond VGA.

Comment: @StackAbstraction Thanks I will try that and I also ordered a DP-DVI adapter. I'll update this question once I've tried those out.

Comment: Is this problem visible during the Windows boot process where you see the loading flag? Does the problem still occur if you boot into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Let's scan. I don't have much idea to this, but depending on the PC, you could 'save' the resolution manually if it doesn't save automatically. I used to use a Dell with resolution of UHD (4K) but stuck at HD (2K) so I tried changing resolution to native but won't save after reboot. I tried changing resolution to native again, but this time after changing resolution I press 'manual save' and it worked! Depending on your hardware, this 'manual save' button is there only if you use Windows 10 and the monitor can support UHD.

Comment: If the button is there only in Win 10, how does it help the OP, who's using Win 7?  Just asking.

Comment: Then I must edit the software of Windows 7 and add an auto-save button.

Comment: Now more people are using Windows 10 than Windows 7, because to some people, Windows 7 is outdated.

Comment: Windows 7 is outdated, like 2008.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp) Windows 7 has a 43% market share.